# Date Conversion C#.net

Tags: .net, c#-3.0

I have string in which it has Date of type- 'mm-dd-yyyy';

I have to convert it into "dd-mm-yyyy".

```
   DateTime changedFormatDate = DateTime.ParseExact("02-27-2012", "mm-dd-yyyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

but the converted value is: 27:01:2012 00:02:00

I want it to be 27-02-2012.

What is the correct sysntax please?

Comment: -1 Date conversion in .net has to be the most asked about topic on StackOverflow. And this exact question has been asked dozens of times. Do a search.

Comment: This is not a valid date format: "02-27-2-2012"

Comment: can the person downvoted the question inform what's wrong with this question?

Comment: basically it says that this question has been asked before, maybe not with the exact format but very similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DateTime.ParseExact("02-27-2012", "MM-dd-yyyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

Note the fixed date string (got rid of the extra `2`) and the `MM` - which meanths months: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx